# How to use adaptive chunking

Tags: timescaledb

I try to use adaptive chunking with timescaleDb 1.0.0. But it does not work as expected.

1. I am creating a hypertable with `chunk_target_size => 'estimate'`.
2. When I check the chunk_target_size it is ~120million - which seems reasonable
3. Now I start a test-program that will loop for 5k times and insert 1k rows per transaction (so only 5million rows in total)

   - When I then check the chunk-sizes, I see ~3.5k chunks which are only 152kB (the first one is 88B)!

**What am I missing?**

### SQL statements

1-Create hypertable

```sql
SELECT create_hypertable('mytable', 'time', chunk_target_size => 'estimate';
```

2-Check the chunk_target_size

```sql
select table_name, chunk_target_size from _timescaledb_catalog.hypertable;
```

3-Check the chunksizes

```sql
SELECT distinct total_size FROM chunk_relation_size_pretty('mytable');
```

### Additional info

**Fixed chunk size**:

When I set the chunk_target_size to 100MB, the chunk_target_size will be ~104 million. But after inserting data the max. chunk_relation_size will also be only 152kB

**chunk_time_interval**

When I set the chunk_time_interval instead of the chunk_target_size I get larger chunk_relation_sizes.

## Update (2.11.2018)

I used [PGTune](https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/) to improve the database-configuration. The `shared_buffers` was only 128MB - now it's 1280MB.
With this change the `chunk_target_size` has increased to about 1.2billion, but the generated chunks are still only 152kB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a quote from the slack channel:

> There are two chunk "fill" thresholds that need to be reached for adaptive chunking to kick in. One is associated with the size (number of bytes) and the other with the interval length. These thresholds protect against acting on chunks that are "underfilled". So, if you insert sparse data  so that chunks do not exceed *both* thresholds, adaptive chunking will not change any intervals.

So it seems, that my use-case cannot use the estimation feature.
Also note, that the [adaptive chunking](https://docs.timescale.com/v0.12/using-timescaledb/adaptive-chunking) feature is still in beta

**UPDATE 04.2019**

The [adaptive chunking](https://docs.timescale.com/v0.12/api#set_adaptive_chunking) feature is now deprecated (in version 1.2)

Answer (score 0):

I would have to see more in order to give you a more accurate answer (perhaps try our Slack for more synchronous help?).

I would check that you remake the hypertables after updating your shared memory settings. The estimate will still be based on your previous memory settings until you run that again. It is not clear if you remade the hypertables after changing shared memory.

Comment: thanks for the answer - I've already used slack and added a quote from there in my own answer.